# Adobe Air file avoid opening

Tags: air, adobe

After creating an adobe air file, I am able to open it using winrar or any other archiving program and see all the contents including the code of my program.

Is there a way to avoid this? Some sort of encryption or something?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The '.air' file is as much an archive as say. a XPS file.

The question is why do you want such a thing? To avoid source sharing?

If you have issues sharing your source, why don't you use put javascript code on your server and pull them from client side. Of course, this'll mean that they don't work when their network or your server is down.

Comment: Yes, all my source code is visible. I just realised that after installation of the application, all of the source code lies in the installation folder. I need a way to protect my code without going online.

Comment: I was hoping there would be a better option than obfuscating each and every js file. Cause I have html files, images etc too.

Comment: I don't see how you will get there. Resources, however can be compiled into a SWC.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by SWC?

Comment: But thats for flex. I wanted something for AJAX+HTML.

Comment: You have the DRM problem - your code needs to be in the clear to run, but that means it can be stolen. There is no solution, I'm afraid.